# Create an icon for docker image

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I create docker image of my application (songkong/songkong) but I notice it doesnt have an icon whereas many other docker images do, how do I add an icon to the docker image ?

(my docker image is available on docker hub)

Comment: Unless this is a payed dockerhub option I totally missed, I'm affraid the "many others" are all official images. So you _just_ have to through the validation process for your app image to become official on dockerhub. Good luck ;)

Comment: errm, okay how do i get an application validated ?

Comment: Last paragraph on this doc should be a good start: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_images/

Comment: Right well that doesnt sound very practical one a single application, seems ot be more think like various database/linux etc base images

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all official images have an associated icon. For instance, [`adoptopenjdk`](https://hub.docker.com/_/adoptopenjdk).

An image like [logstash](https://hub.docker.com/_/logstash) would use a [logo.png](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/5fa6f9ace41aa0ded6bdf4df56f746edf43c5843/logstash/logo.png) in the [`docker-library/docs`](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/) repository.

[`docker-library/docs` issue 1060](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/issues/1060) asked: How do you add the icon for an image on Docker Hub?

But... there does not seem to be any formal process associated to that.
Only to [become an official image](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_images/).

Comment: Perhaps I should ask - Why cant you add an icon then, because Officia Images are clearly not the approach expected of developers creating end user applications

Comment: @PaulTaylor I agree. My point is: you don't seen to be able to add an image, except for official images, and even then, it is not trivial.

Comment: What is the answer now regarding the ability to add a logo/ icon? Is this exclusively for official images?

Comment: @vanthome I don't have any new information regarding that.